# RDP equivalent to SSH port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2012-r2, port-forwarding, rdp, ssh-tunnel

I'm connecting from one Windows machine to another using RDP.  I'd like to forward traffic headed for `localhost:81` to a machine accessible to the remote machine via its internal network on a local IP address, let's say `10.90.228.163`.  So I want the TCP traffic to go:

```
client --> localhost:81 --> [rdphost] --> 10.90.228.163:81 --> server
```

With OpenSSH and PuTTY, I could do this using local port forwarding; forward local port `81` to `10.90.228.163:123`.  Is there a way to do this with RDP instead?

Comment: Possibly relevant: you can [install Remote Desktop Gateway on Server 2012](https://ryanmangansitblog.com/2013/03/27/deploying-remote-desktop-gateway-rds-2012/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not possible with RDP.

You can install an SSH server on windows and continue to use SSH.

Alternatively, you can use netsh to do TCP forwarding as described in [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11535395/212107):

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=81 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=81 connectaddress=10.90.228.163
```

Note that this will behave different ftom SSH: The connection to the connectaddress/port will originate from the machine it is listening on, instead of the target machine. Also, it will not be encrypted. This is rather a Windows equivalent for IPtables portforwarding, than for an SSH tunnel.

Comment: Will that `netsh` command do what I want, though?  I don't want to forward traffic from one port to another on the *local* machine, I want to forward it from the local machine to a *remote* machine.

Comment: Keeping in mind that the `portproxy` forwarding does not provide the encryption that SSH does.